# Average Response time of items

Tags: sql, sql-server

Its a very basic question, and I am just confused.

```
Response Time | Item
    2           1
    3           1
    4           1
    1           1 
    4           2 
    4           2 
    4           2
    8           2
    1           3
```

If column A is the number of days takes by each item (column B) . What is the average response time of each item in column B and the total average response time.

Comment: could you explain it again with other words? i can't figure out, what you are going to do

Comment: I'm not so sure about what is the question there.

Comment: I want to find the average response time . I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be easy like:

```
SELECT Item
      ,SUM(ResponseTime) AS Total_ResponseTime
      ,AVG(ResponseTime) AS Average_ResponseTime
      ,(SELECT AVG(ResponseTime) FROM mytab) as Total_Average_ResponseTime
  FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Item
```

If you wanna reproduce my result, you can use this link: http://rextester.com/LIV1334

Comment: Can you explain what the formula for the average would be like? and I want to find out the total average response time. Sorry I made an error, I edited it now

Comment: do i get it right? you want to have the average over all items? not the average per Item?

Comment: Both! average per item and total average as well.

Comment: @Rahul i updated my query and added the Total Average of all Items

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for?

```
select item, avg([respone time]) 
from items
group by item
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT item, AVG(response_time)
FROM table
GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward aggregation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql

```
select AVG(ResponseTime)
    , Item
from YourTable
group by Item
```